# Text game assistance

Tags: java, text

this may be a simple fix and a silly question but I am still new to learning java. I am currently working on a code for class that bases on a text game. The code below is what was given to us out of our text book to work on the game. I changed the actual text in the text file mainly and did not do much to the code but I am receiving the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at BradySkuza58.getRoom(BradySkuza58.java:143)
    at BradySkuza58.loadRoomsFromFile(BradySkuza58.java:90)
    at BradySkuza58.main(BradySkuza58.java:39)
```

This is the code I used for the text game.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

    class Room
    {
        int roomNumber;
    String roomName;
    String description;
    int numExits;
    String[] exits = new String[20];
    int[] destinations = new int[20];
}

public class BradySkuza58
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // initialize rooms from file
        Room[] rooms = loadRoomsFromFile("textadventurerooms.txt");

        //showAllRooms(rooms); // for debugging

        // Okay, so let's play the game!
        int currentRoom = 0;
        String ans;
        while ( currentRoom >= 0 )
        {
            Room cur = rooms[currentRoom];
            System.out.print( cur.description );
            System.out.print("> ");
            ans = keyboard.nextLine();

            // See if what they typed matches any of our exit names
            boolean found = false;
            for ( int i=0; i<cur.numExits; i++ )
            {
                if ( cur.exits[i].equals(ans) )
                {
                    found = true;
                    // if so, change our next room to that exit's room number
                    currentRoom = cur.destinations[i];
                }
            }
            if ( ! found )
            System.out.println("Sorry, I don't understand.");
        }

    }

    public static Room[] loadRoomsFromFile( String filename )
    {
        Scanner file = null;
        try
        {
            file = new Scanner(new java.io.File(filename));
        }
        catch ( java.io.IOException e )
        {
            System.err.println("Sorry, I can't read from the file '" +filename + "'.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        int numRooms = file.nextInt();
        Room[] rooms = new Room[numRooms];

        // initialize rooms from file
        int roomNum = 0;
        while ( file.hasNext() )
        {
            Room r = getRoom(file);
            if ( r.roomNumber != roomNum )
            {
                System.err.println("Reading room # " + r.roomNumber + ", but" + roomNum + " was expected.");
                System.exit(2);
            }
            rooms[roomNum] = r;
            roomNum++;
        }
        file.close();

        return rooms;
    }

    public static void showAllRooms( Room[] rooms )
    {
        for ( Room r : rooms )
        {
            String exitString = "";
            for ( int i=0; i<r.numExits; i++ )
            exitString += "\t" + r.exits[i] + " (" + r.destinations[i] +")";
            System.out.println( r.roomNumber + ") " + r.roomName + "\n" +exitString );
        }
    }

    public static Room getRoom( Scanner f )
    {
        // any rooms left in the file?
        if ( ! f.hasNextInt() )
        return null;

        Room r = new Room();
        String line;

        // read in the room # for errorchecking later
        r.roomNumber = f.nextInt();
        f.nextLine(); // skip "\n" after room #

        r.roomName = f.nextLine();

        // read in the room's description r.description = "";
        while ( true )
        {
            line = f.nextLine();
            if ( line.equals("%%") )
            break;
            r.description += line + "\n";
        }

        // finally, we'll read in the exits
        int i = 0;
        while ( true )
        {
            line = f.nextLine();
            if ( line.equals("%%") )
            break;
            String[] parts = line.split(":");
            r.exits[i] = parts[0];
            r.destinations[i] = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
            i++;
        }
        r.numExits = i;

        // should be done; return the Room
        return r;
    }

}
```

line 39

```
Room[] rooms = loadRoomsFromFile("textadventurerooms.txt");
```

line 90

```
    Room r = getRoom(file);
```

line 143

```
    line = f.nextLine();
```

I did not attach the text file itself but I can if it is needed to find the error.

Comment: Can you highlight lines 143, 90 and 39?

Comment: Could you just put a comment next to the important line numbers (there are multiple lines `line = f.nextLine();`). Also please post a sample of the text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that your text file does not have as many lines are your program expects (you are trying to call `nextLine()` after already reaching EOF. Double check that your text file matches what you want. Not having the text file it is tough to give more detail. Based on where it is make sure that you are breaking out of that `while` loop. You can also check to see if there is another line by calling `hasNextLine()`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Turns out I was missing a line that was needed in my text file.

Answer (score 0):

Add a line "%%" to your room definition file. Your parser requires that.